# Javascript Variables.. and output

Tags: javascript, variables, drop-down-menu

Below a javascript, put it doesn't work.

```
  <script>

        var AccounStelectd = "{F060E2C5-5722-4AB9-A635-C1C40FDCF999}"; 

        for (var i=0;i<Accounts.length;i++)
        {         
            var str1 = Accounts[i];
            var chunks = str1.split("-");

            if (chunks[1] = AccounStelectd)
            {
                var x = "selected=selected";
            }
            else
            {
                var x = "";
            }

            document.write("<option x value='chunks[1]'>" + chunks[0] + "</option>>");
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: `Accounts.length`... where is `Accounts`?

Comment: Accounts is an array with id-name already filled somewhere else in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumin accounts is already defined in some other code, you are missing '=' in if condition. It would be

```
  if (chunks[1] == AccounStelectd)
```

Use == if you want to check the value only otherwise use === to check both value and data type.

Also concatination is required in options

```
 document.write("<option "+x+" value='"+chunks[1]+"'>" + chunks[0] + "</option>");
```

Comment: @user2985353 please check the answer if it's able to resolve your question